# What is the Grothendieck group of finitely generated $R[G]$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, $G$ a finite group and $R[G]$ the group ring. What is the definition of the Grothendieck group of finitely generated $R[G]$-modules?

How is this connected to the Grothendieck group of a ring?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the notion of the [Grothendieck group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) of the *category* of finitely generated $R[G]$-modules (sometimes this is just named the Grothendieck group of
finitely generated $R[G]$-modules). 
The Grothendieck group is defined in the same way as before as the abelian group with one generator $[M]$ for each isomorphism class of objects of the category, and one relation  $[A]-[B]+[C] = 0$ for each exact sequence
$A\hookrightarrow B\twoheadrightarrow C$.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that the Grothendieck group over an arbitrary ring $R$ is the Grothendieck group of the category of finitely generated *projective* $R$-modules (and not merely finitely generated)?